# NHibernate QueryOver C#, selecting a specific property of a joined Entity to List field within a Dto

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I was wondering how to do the following in QueryOver (NHibernate 4.0.4)

Say I have this set of classes

```
class Student 
{
    public virtual long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Exam> Exams { get; set; }
}

class Exam 
{
    public virtual string Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual int Score { get; set; }
    //Many more unneeded properties
}

class StudentDto 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Subjects { get; set; }
    public IList<int> Scores { get; set; }
}
```

How would I go about getting all students along with their Subjects and Scores without fetching the whole entities?

The functionality I am going for is:

```
foreach(var exam in student.Exams)
{
    dto.Subjects.Add(exam.Subject);
    dto.Scores.Add(exam.Score);
}
```

But hopefully using some of NHibernate's functionality like SelectList

Basically what I am trying to do is something along these lines:

```
StudentDto dto = null;
Student student = null;
Exam exam = null;
```

```
QueryOver<Student>(() => student)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(st => st.Exams.Select(x => x.Subject)).WithAlias(() => dto.Subjects)
        .Select(st => st.Exams.Select(x => x.Score)).WithAlias(() => dto.Scores)
    )
```

I've tried the above, I get an exception that the object is out of scope

```
QueryOver<Student>(() => student)
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(() => student.Exams.Select(x => x.Subject)).WithAlias(() => dto.Subjects)
        .Select(() => student.Exams.Select(x => x.Score)).WithAlias(() => dto.Scores)
    )
```

I've tried this, throws a null reference exception, I've also tried the above with a ternary operator to check for whether or not the lists are null and pass an empty list if so, didn't work

**EDIT**

I would like to return a list of StudentDtos with every one of them containing a list of the respective student's Scores and Subjects.

So a structure somewhat resembling this

```
StudentDto
    -> long ID
    -> List<string> subjects -> Math
                             -> Physics
                             -> etc..
    -> List<int> scores      -> 100
                             -> 94
                             -> etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what JoinAlias is for. If the goal is to get students by some filter then this might look like this

```
Exam exam = null;
var data = session.QueryOver<Student>()
    //.Where( whatever)
    .JoinAlias(s => s.Exams, () => exam)
    .Select(s => s.Id, s => exam.Subject, s => exam.Score)
    .OrderBy(s => s.Id).Asc
    .List<object[]>();

var studentDtos = new List<StudentDto>();
foreach (var item in data)
{
    var id = (long)item[0];
    StudentDto current = studentDtos.LastOrDefault();
    if (studentDtos.Count == 0 || current.Id != id)
    {
        studentDtos.Add(current = new StudentDto { Id = id });
    }
    current.Subjects.Add((string)item[1]);
    current.Scores.Add((int)item[2]);
}
```

Comment: The goal is to retreive Students along with their Scores/Subjects, without returning the whole Exam object, since in my case it contains a lot of Hibernate proxies which I would like to avoid returning since I would only need the 2 mentioned arrays.

Comment: @Lazar this code worked in a test application. What didn't work for you?